# How I could connect my forge model to a Postgres Database?

Tags: database, postgresql, forge

I am actually working on integration of real time data to my forge model. I use Postgres database which is linked to timescale DB. I want to import the data of each element based on its ID in real time as showed in this screen by red.
To sum up, two tasks:
- connecting forge model to my database and import the data of each element
- update the data in real time of each element

In red, the properties that should be connected to my database:

[image]